# 502 bad gateway on wildfly-9.01 and apache

Tags: performance, apache, wildfly, wildfly-9, http-status-code-502

we are using wildfly-9.01 on azure environment and using application gateway and WAF services.

We observe 502 in apache log in underload and application became unresponsive.

We are using following configuration.

OS: centos-8(32 vcpus, 256 GiB memory)

web server: apache with modjk

application server: wildfly-9.01(40 GB memory is allocated)

Below is the Wildfly configuration:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:1.1">
    <worker name="default" task-max-threads="500"/>
    <buffer-pool name="default"/>
</subsystem>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        <ajp-listener name="ajpListener" scheme="http" socket-binding="ajp" max-header-size="50000" max-post-size="5368709120" max-parameters="5000000" allow-equals-in-cookie-value="true"/>
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" max-header-size="50000" max-post-size="5368709120" max-parameters="5000000" allow-equals-in-cookie-value="true"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost"/>
    </server>
    <servlet-container name="default">
        <jsp-config x-powered-by="false"/>
        <websockets/>
    </servlet-container>
    <filters>
        <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="My company"/>
        <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="My company Application"/>
    </filters>
</subsystem>
```

Below is the Apache Keep alive config:

```
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 300
KeepAliveTimeout 600
TimeOut 1200
```

any suggestions for things to look at or try to avoid 502?